# How to create administration account of keycloak on AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, keycloak, amazon-ecs

I am working on AWS ECS. I have uploaded Keycloak image to aws ecs, but when i run task and open that using public id, i am getting problem in administration account. There is no admin account at first and i am not able to create it.

**What i have done : I have created task definition using jboss/keycloak:latest image url. Then created one cluster and run task using above task definition.
Issue : creating admin account on running task.**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what do you mean "when i run task", how did you run it? What are your environment variables while running? " i am not able to create it.", why, did you get any exception?

Comment: @cmlonder meaning of running task is that i am able to run task in cluster in aws ecs, and after running that task i will get one pubic id to access data from that running task. So, i am getting that ip and for checking that ip in browser i get welcom page of keycloak but not able to create admin account within it. AND i have defined 8080 port to access container in across the world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using official keycloak image [here](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-containers/tree/master/server) then you can pass folowing environment variables to generate admin user:

```
KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=password
```

Or if you don't use keycloak image (maybe you build yourself), you can also run the following command directly which does the same

```
/opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/add-user-keycloak.sh --user "admin" --password "password"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I finally found where to write environment variable in aws ecs.